# FileNotFoundError while using pipenv to create virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

I am using Windows 7, python 3.7.6. When i try to create virtual environment using pipenv, i get following error , please help me to resolve this error.When I tried to create virtual environment using venv , then it creates successfully, but pipenv gives this error.

```
D:\MOSH Course\10_Python_Package_Index>pip install pipenv
Collecting pipenv
  Using cached pipenv-2018.11.26-py3-none-any.whl (5.2 MB)
Collecting virtualenv
  Downloading virtualenv-20.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.6 MB 84 kB/s
Collecting certifi
  Using cached certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (41.2.0)
Collecting virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5
  Using cached virtualenv_clone-0.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8" in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.5.0)
Collecting filelock<4,>=3.0.0
  Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting appdirs<2,>=1.4.3
  Downloading appdirs-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.12.0 in c:\users\tejaswita\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.14.0)
Collecting distlib<1,>=0.3.0; sys_platform == "win32"
  Downloading distlib-0.3.0.zip (571 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 571 kB 24 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata<2,>=0.12; python_version < "3.8"->virtualenv->pipenv) (2.2.0)
Installing collected packages: filelock, appdirs, distlib, virtualenv, certifi, virtualenv-clone, pipenv
    Running setup.py install for distlib ... done
Successfully installed appdirs-1.4.3 certifi-2019.11.28 distlib-0.3.0 filelock-3.0.12 pipenv-2018.11.26 virtualenv-20.0.0 virtualenv-clone-0.5.3

D:\MOSH Course\10_Python_Package_Index>pipenv install requests
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Installing requests…
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\python\Scripts\pipenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\click\decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 254, in install
    editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1927, in do_install
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1421, in pip_install
    c = delegator.run(pip_command, block=block, env=pip_config)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\delegator.py", line 336, in run
    c.run(block=block, binary=binary, cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pipenv\vendor\delegator.py", line 192, in run
    s = subprocess.Popen(self._popen_args, **popen_kwargs)
  File "c:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\python\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem looks like a bug in pipenv for Windows. Sometimes, the blank spaces in the windows folder names can cause this 'file not found' errors.

Removing the blank spaces in the source folder name (D:\MOSH course...) may help.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i tried without blank spaces, but same error comes

Comment: Thanks for verifying, Vaibhavi. The above error can then be considered as a bug in pipenv for Windows.

Comment: Gopinath you are right, i could successfully run the same command in google colab, it must be windows issue.